# Access specifier in SystemVerilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am totally confused in access specifiers `local`,`static`,`virtual`,`protected` and `automatic`. give example or document for the same.
Any Help appreciated a lot.

Answer (score 2):

These access specifiers apply to class member declarations (variables, functions and tasks declared within a class)

- **local**: these members may only be reference from within the class is is declared in.
- **static**: these members are allocated up declaration of a class and are shared between all constructed objects
- **virtual**: apply to class methods(tasks and functions) and are better explained [here](https://verificationacademy.com/forums/systemverilog/how-polymorphism-virtual-functons-inheritance-systemverilog) and [here](http://munjalm.blogspot.com/2013/07/system-verilog-polymorphism.html).
- **automatic**: never used in the declaration of a class or any of its members.

Comment: Then what is the use of automatic?

Comment: See https://verificationacademy.com/forums/systemverilog/what-exact-difference-between-static-tasks/functions-and-automatic-tasks/functions-please-explain-clear-example#reply-44935